# SQL with Python: How do I commit an SQL transaction within a class?

Tags: python, sql-server

My experience with classes is somewhat limited, so I apologize.  I have a Database class.  I create an instance of it and attempt to run SQL functions through it, which work fine and dandy, until I need to save an INSERT INTO with `conn.commit()`.  my code is as follows:-

```
Class DatabaseClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.open_database()

    def open_database(self):
        conn = pyodbc.connect(
                 r"Driver={SQL Server};"
                 r"Server=ServerName;"
                 r"Database=DatabaseName;"
                 r"Trusted_Connection=yes;"
                 )
        self.cursor = conn.cursor()

    def NewRecord()
        self.cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO ....")
        self.conn.commit()

db = DatabaseClass()
db.NewRecord()
```

But I get the error

> "DatabaseClass object has no attribute 'conn'".

What do I have to do so that the `NewRecord` function knows what connection it's dealing with?

Thanks!

Comment: In `open_database()`, change `conn = ..` to `self.conn = ..`.

Comment: Thanks! This worked!